# Deactivate SSL verification in Firefox/Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, ssl, wireshark

I was wondering if it is possible to deactivate SSL verification in Chrome or Firefox, so that I can use Wireshark to trace the communication between a Server with self-signed certificate and a web app. Unfortunately, most of the hints I found were already out-dated or do not work at all.

The problem is that accepting the certificate in Firefox or Chrome results in a different SSL handshake. Wireshark can't decrypt this stream anymore.

When I use a native written app (with Java) and disable SSL verification, Wireshark is able to decrypt the stream correctly.

Does anyone know how to decrypt SSL streams with Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with Java vs Firefox/Chrome, rather with the cipher suites that are in use.

Comment: Sure? I thougt, that wireshark requires a complete handshake which is not interupted by an encryption alert. This what Firefox and chrome do.